# How to run jupyter notebook on Ubuntu using linode server?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, apache2, reverse-proxy, linode

I tried running jupyter notebook in a Linode server, but when I ran the jupyter nootbook and then went on to my browser to open it there I got a "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page".
Below are the steps I took to get to this point.

From: https://www.linode.com/docs/getting-started/#create-a-linode

```
1.Created Linode (UBUNTU 20.04)
2.Removed previous ssh key
3.Logged in with new ssh key
4.Install software updates
```

From: https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/big-data/install-a-jupyter-notebook-server-on-a-linode-behind-an-apache-reverse-proxy/#before-you-begin

```
1.Download and install anaconda
2.Create certificates
3.Configure Jupyter
4.Configure apache reverse proxy
5.Run Jupiter notebook
```

There was a step in the getting started guide about "Update your system's
hosts file" but I don't know what should I do in that step after doing: vim
/etc/hosts from root account so I just: ESC :wq! from it.

I also tried following this link but this one didn't even open anything:
https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-server/
I also tried another to follow another article  (don't have link) where I enabled remote access in the jupyter configuration step but no use.

I have tried downloading anaconda like this:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash ~/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and tried changing certificates with this:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mykey.key -out mycert.pem
```

I tried a few combinations with the URL but only one worked:

1. only the IP address  > this opened the page in the picture
2. https://ipaddress/   > didn't work
3. https://ipaddress/jupyter   > didn't work
4. https://ipaddress:8888/jupyter/    > didn't work
5. ipaddress:8888/jupyter/    > didn't work

Please help me run the notebook.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSqGK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by following this article here:
I only created a root password in server setup. I do not know ways around this. replace `your_server_ip` with your linode ip.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-run-connect-to-jupyter-notebook-on-remote-server

So basically first we setup our Linode server. You can directly log in to the server as root by

```
$ ssh root@your_server_ip
```

Then we add user with sudo priveleges

```
# adduser user
```

You will be asked some information. Just give a password and leave the rest as default if you want.
then

```
# usermod -aG sudo user
```

Then we setup our firewall. If you skip then you will 100% encounter some error.

```
# ufw allow OpenSSH
```

and then allow ssh by

```
# ufw enable
```

Then open a new terminal and log into the user account by

```
$ ssh user@your_server_ip
```

Now we update our workspace

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt -y upgrade
```

You should have python by default. You can check it by `python3 -V`
Next we install pip and some other packages. You may try to skip this step.

```
$ sudo apt install -y python3-pip
$ sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
```

I did not have a need to set up a virtual environment but you may choose to do so if you require.
Now we install jupyter notebook

```
$ python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

And its still not done yet!!! Then log out of the server by using

```
$ exit
```

Now we connect to the jupyter notebook application with ssh tunneling.

```
$ ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 user@your_server_ip
```

Here 8888 is Jupyter Notebook’s default port. Feel free to change `8000` though. If there are no errors from this command, it will log you into your remote server. Then run the Jupyter Notebook application

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

To connect to Jupyter Notebook, use your favorite web browser to navigate to the local port on the local host: http://localhost:8000
Use the token generated on the terminal to log into jupyter.
And Voila!!

Edit: Thank you David for the advice.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Answers that are little more than a link will become useless if the website moves.